# JQuery 2.0.3 Chrome Error Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, jquery-2.0

I'm building out an HTML5 page. I'm using JQuery in it, and I'm getting the following two console errors.

```
Denying load of chrome-extension://kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh/js/jquery.min.map. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension. localhost/:1

GET chrome-extension://invalid/  chrome-extension://invalid/:1
```

As far as I can tell everything is declared normally. Here's the top of my html page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <link href="css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/archivo-narrow.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

What's triggering this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using the Chrome extension Windows Resizer it could be to do with that see http://windowresizer.userecho.com/topic/185143-exception-in-development-tools-in-chrome-dev-m-29015302-66-and-29015353-611/ I am getting the same error. If I disable the extension I no longer get the error.

Comment: I am using that. I'll try that out and see if it fixes it.

Comment: The Chrome extension "ScrollMaps" did it for me. I found the issue by searching the Chrome Extensions page for the extension id given in the error.

Comment: Basically there are apparently **several different extensions that cause this**. Just try disabling the last one you installed and continue disabling in backwards chronological order until error disappears.

Answer (score 11):

When you don't use jQuery from CDN (you download jQuery for yourself, then include it), it will failed to find its source map, to fix this error download jquery source map

You can find source map path in **Resource Tab** in **Developer Tool**, then open your jQuery file, you will find something like this

```
/*! jQuery v2.0.3 | (c) 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license
//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-2.0.3.min.map
*/
```

Then go to http://code.jquery.com/sourceMappingURL, in this case = http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.map, then save it in same directory as you save your jQuery file

Comment: +1. This fixed my issue. I was jumping from my previous use of jq1.7, so I had no idea I was missing an extra file. (I had to add `"web_accessible_resources": ["jquery-2.0.3.min.map"],` to my manifest.json, but I wouldn't have figured this out otherwise.)

Answer (score 10):

If you just want to temperately remove this message, turn off the **source maps**.

For Chrome User: press Ctrl + Shift + I, click the gear icon in right hand side to open the **Settings**, un-check the **Enable source maps**.

For other user, read it [Developer Tools - Source maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/)

Detail of problem: it is because the page included a minified JS/CSS/resource, and it was attached a mapping path of original file. Unfortunately, the file is missing in mapping path.

Comment: My firstborn, sir - he is yours. Come and collect him at your leisure.

Answer (score 1):

Did u registered all ur files correctly in the chrome manifest file? I Guess something is wrong there